# openssh won't find .ssh directory on cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I just installed Cygwin, and openssh ignores the known_hosts file. My guess is that openssh does not even see the ~/.ssh folder. I've defined a Windows environment variable HOME, and Cygwin does start in %HOME%. The permissions on ~/.ssh are 600, and permissions inside ~/.ssh are 600 for everything except that known_hosts and *.pub are 644. All i get is

```
$ ssh -vvv -Y foo
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
ssh: Could not resolve hostname learnlab: hostname nor servname provided, or not known
```

Note that I don't have the line `debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config`, and what's even odder, Cygwin doesn't install /etc/ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had to not only set %HOME%, but also to create a mount point for /home/myhome.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab.d/myhome 
c:/Users/myhome/My\040Documents /home/myhome    ntfs    binary  0       0
```